# Recovering from connection time exceeded in JPA

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

Running a very job (indexing tens of thousands of document with database look up), I get this error:
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02399: exceeded maximum connect time, you are being logged off

Error occurs with at a repository.findOne call.

The process is running under tomcat.

What I need to do ( I think) is log back into Oracle and get a new connection. However, JPA pretty effectively hides all that detail. (And Spring even further). How do I proceed?

Comment: How are you connecting? Have you configured a dataSource?

Comment: yes. I am. I have since discovered that the Oracle system manager had imposed a 4 hour time limit on connections because he was having problems with zombie connections. He has now changed that to 4 days.

Comment: Still means you will have an issue every 4 days unless you configure your datasource to reconnect. You will need to add settings so that connections become stale and are discarded well before then to avoid odd issues with your app.

Comment: Session times out after 30 minutes of inactivity. My apps werent the source of the oracle stale connections. However, what I am interested in is how exactly to do force a reconnect? With spring, my database interactions are: a/ set datasource; b/ query a repository. Spring auto-magic is managing the connections.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a timeout like this, reconnecting isn't your primary problem. You need to get your timeout long enough or your transactions short enough to not trigger a timeout.

The concern of reconnecting is normally transparently taken care of a connection pool, which you most certainly should use for everything except maybe tests. But this won't fix your immediate problem that the connection gets closed and your transaction rolled back.

**Update:**
The problem doesn't seem to be transaction duration, but connection duration.

If this is really true you should talk to the DBA responsible for this timeout, because IMHO it doesn't make sense to close connections that are used just because they are open for some given time.

You can't/don't want to manually close or reopen connections. This is the task of the connection pool. If you close a connection you got from the connection pool, you are not really closing it, but returning it to the connection pool.

Instead, configure your connection pool to close connection and create new ones on a regular basis. How this works depends on the connection pool you are using.

Comment: I am  only querying, not doing any transactions. However, problem was the Oracle job killing off connections longer than 4 hours,

Comment: You can't interact with Oracle nor with an EntityManager without a transaction.

Comment: Well em and transaction  manager are effectively autoconnected and datasource set in spring config.
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages="nz.cri.gns.mapservice.repository",
        queryLookupStrategy=QueryLookupStrategy.Key.CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND,
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager"
)
I only interact via repository. The problem is how do I explicitly manage that connection?

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for those comments. I have got connection timeout extended to 4 days so hopefully fixes the issue.